# code to insert an iFrame in each article somes from database

Tags: database, asp-classic

I have an ASP website with thousands of articles comes from SQL database.

In the ASP web page the code that pulls out\shows the article is: `<%=the_article%>` only.
Is there a code to insert iFrame in each article?

For example: I want every 10 lines of the article to show a banner, that means that if an article is of 35 lines, Than the banner should show up 3 times, after line 10, 20 and line 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use `Split()` on each linebreak, to get each line into an array.

So, you would do this:

```
ArticleLines = Split(the_Article,Chr(13))
```

Then you can loop through them and insert your "banner" whenever you want (ie: When `i=10`.

If you don't know the number of lines the page will render the text, and the lines are not separated with a linebreak character for your `Split()` function to find, then you would need to loop through the text at certain # of characters based on a manual digit number that you would manually have to set based on the display port of the article.  Or you can use something like jQuery to inject the banners.

Comment: It might also help if you have closing </p> tags in which case this might be easier?

Comment: Could you be more specific giving me the whole exact script I should add? since I am not a programmer. Thanks